# Need to split a column of values into multiple columns, based on the id they are referring to

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Basically, I have this dummy table:

| People | Group ID |
| --- | --- |
| Albert | 1 |
| Bernard | 1 |
| Charles | 2 |
| Daniel | 2 |
| Elizabeth | 3 |
| Francis | 3 |

And what I would like to have is this:

| People 1 | People 2 | Group ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | Bernard | 1 |
| Charles | Daniel | 2 |
| Elizabeth | Francis | 3 |

I tried to pivot and unpivot here and there mindlessly to no avail, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powerquery,

Right-click the GroupID column and Group By...

Allow the default options and hit ok

Change the last part of the formula in the formula bar (or in home...advanced editor...) from

```
= Table.Group(Source, {"Group ID"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}})
```

to

```
 = Table.Group(Source, {"Group ID"}, {{"Count", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([People], Text.From), ","), type text}})
```

that combines the People column into one column separated by commas

Then right click that column and split column by delimiter, for each occurrence of a comma

Full sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Group ID"}, {{"Count", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([People], Text.From), ","), type text}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Count.1", "Count.2"})
in #"Split Column by Delimiter"

//fancy version that includes Column titles and auto adjusts for dynamic number of columns
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Group ID"}, {{"Count", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([People], Text.From), ","), type text}}),
DynamicColumnList = List.Transform({1..List.Max(Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each List.Count(Text.PositionOfAny([Count], {","}, Occurrence.All)))[Custom])+1}, each "Person." & Text.From(_)),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows","Count",Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv),DynamicColumnList  )
in  #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

---

Another way ....

Right-click the GroupID column and Group By...

Allow the default options and hit ok

Change the last part of the formula in the formula bar (or in home...advanced editor...) from

```
= Table.Group(Source, {"Group ID"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}})
```

to

```
= Table.Group(Source, {"Group ID"}, {{"count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1), type table}})
```

Use arrows atop new column and expand [x] People and [x] Index

Click select index column, transform pivot, choose People as value, advanced options, don't aggregate

full sample code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Group = Table.Group(Source, {"Group ID"}, {{"count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1), type table}}),
#"Expanded count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Group, "count", {"People", "Index"}, {"People", "Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded count", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded count", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US")[Index]), "Index", "People")
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a mil.